# Converter string para código-fonte JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, se tenho uma variável string que armazena *"alert('teste');"*, como posso executá-la ou convertê-la em código-fonte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) que avalia(e executa) o código representado numa string. Exemplo:

```js
var comm = "alert('teste');";
eval(comm); //Executa o alert
```